# Force buffered output out of function

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have this script running on a Raspberry Pi to show a logo on a Oled display.
I am executing the script in unbuffered mode with the -u option.
The time sleep inside the function doesn't work.
Lines and text only show on the display when the return line is executed.
For the time being I have positioned the time.sleep after the function' call and it works but I need it inside the function because of some other feature I need to add to the function.
Any idea on how I can solve the buffering issue in this context?

```
from luma.core.render import canvas
from luma.oled.device import sh1106
from PIL import ImageFont, Image

device = sh1106(i2c(port=1, address=0x3C), rotate=0)
device.clear()

def logo3():
      #while True:
       with canvas(device) as logo:
        logo.rectangle((0, 48, 115, 12), outline="white", fill="black") 
        #diamond
        logo.line([(0,30),(15,15)], fill = "white")
                #top feature
        logo.line([(15,15),(15,22)], fill = "white")             
        logo.line([(12,22),(18,22)], fill = "white")       
        #centre feature
        logo.line([(0,30),(5,30)], fill = "white")
                     #bottom arc   
        shape = [(12, 39), (18,45)]   
        logo.arc(shape, start = 164, end = 16, fill ="white")       
        #text
        logo.text((60,0), 'Serial xxxx', font = font3, fill = "white")
        
        #time.sleep(2.5). —!!!!— This doesn’t work here—!!!— The code above shows only after time.sleep is elapsed
        return   
  
logo3()
time.sleep(2.5).   #—!!!!— It does work here—!!!—
```

Comment: have you tried using sleep outside of the `with` block? it may be buffering while the context is active.

Comment: @Altareos yes I did try that

Comment: What makes you think it is related to being unbuffered?

Comment: Does it work if you temporarily remove the `logo.text(...Serial...)` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Even removing the text line the outcome doesn't change. Since the return in this case case has no options, it is there just to end the function. This makes me thinking that  the output is buffered until exiting the function. I may be wrong but I have no other thoughts at present.

Comment: Did you try without unbuffered mode?

Comment: I don't understand why it's in a `while True:` loop either?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I have removed the wile : true. It was there for other reasons which do not make sense with the reduced version of the code I posted. However, no difference in the behaviour. Yes, I did try with -u and without. Still no difference. The reason why I would like the time.sleep in the function, is to reiterate between the letters of the logo and make them showing up one at time with a 0.2 sec interval. Like in a terminal. This feature doesn't show in the code above because it is not relevant to the issue I am experiencing. Just to keep it simple.

Comment: It seems a bit misleading, to me at least, to mention unbuffering in the title and again in the question when, as you say, the unbuffering makes no difference. It might be making people approach the question with the wrong impression.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, you right. It should be force buffered output out of function. Sorry,  my English...

Answer (score 0):

try defining a function that just does "time.sleep" and put it where you want.

Comment: Just tested it. Unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).